# Output Stream to webpage

Tags: java, html, http, tomcat, servlets

I am writing a very crude web interface for some server tests.

My servlet code essentially looks like this:

```
import Application.*;

@WebServlet("/runtest")
public class RunTestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(View.runTestPageHTML());
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Application.runTest();
        doGet(request,response);
    }
}
class View{
    public static String runTestPageHTML(){
        return "<html><body><form><submit value='run'></form></body></html>";
    }
}
```

This has 2 problems. Tomcat can and will start a new job if the form is re-sent, and there is no feedback as to the progress of the job.

I basically want Application.runTest() to reroute all gets to `http://<server>/runtest` to logger.out and ignore all posts until the job is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your job is in Application.runTest(), right?
If runTest() is a static method, you can use a global variable to control one execution per request.

```
    public class Application{
           private static boolean inExecution = false;

           public static void runTest(){
              if(!inExecution){
                 inExecution = true;
                 //(...) yout job
                 inExecution = false;
              }

           }
     }
```